# Can "or leave a comment" be removed from the on hold instructions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, on-hold

Here's the current language at the bottom closed/on hold questions:

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](/help/closed-questions), please [edit the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/248006/edit) or [leave a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248006/).

I've noticed a pattern among new users; they will too often leave a comment instead of editing the question. Since leaving a comment doesn't bump a question or place it in the re-open queue, I think it should be removed from this dialog.

Comment: That would prevent other users from making suggestions on how the OP could improve his question (I don't have enough rep to downvote this request).

Comment: @DavidPostill changing the wording would **not** prevent anyone from leaving comments. It is not my suggestion to lock comments on held questions.

Comment: Perhaps "or leave a comment" should not be shown to the OP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good call. The guidance now reads:

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit your question.

For duplicates, the guidance reads:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.